# Amazon MWS API Call Using Delphi/Indy

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, indy, indy10, amazon-mws

I'm developing a simple application to "talk" to the Amazon MWS API. Because a lot of existing code is at play here, I need to get this done in Delphi 2010 with Indy 10 (10.5.5) components, which I have used successfully to integrate with many other APIs in the past. However, the Amazon API seems to be incredibly sensitive to the smallest of details, to the point that all my calls are being denied with the already infamous "SignatureDoesNotMatch" error message.

Here's what I have accomplished so far:

1) My app will assemble a request, sign it with HMAC-SHA256 (using the OpenSSL libraries) and send it to the Amazon server endpoint.

2) The HMAC signature alone proved to be a challenge in itself, but it's now working correctly 100% of the time (as verified against requests generated by the Amazon Scrachpad).

However, as I pointed out earlier, my requests are always rejected by the MWS server with the SignatureDoesNotMatch error, even though they are verifiably correct.  The only thing I can think of that could be causing problems is the way Indy may be handling the POST requests, specifically the text encoding process.

Has anyone been successful in connecting a Delphi/Indy client to MWS?  If so, what kind of TIdHTTP settings were used?  Here's what I have:

```
procedure TAmazon.TestGetOrder(OrderID:String);

const AwsAccessKey = 'MyAccessKey';
      AwsSecretKey = 'MySecretKey';
      MerchantID = 'MyMerchantID';
      MarketplaceID = 'MyMarketplaceID';
      ApiVersion = '2013-09-01';
      CallUri = '/Orders/2013-09-01';

var HTTP:TIdHTTP;
    SSL:TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    SS:TStringStream;
    Params:TStringList;
    S,Timestamp,QueryString,Key,Value:String;
    i:Integer;

begin
   HTTP:=TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
   SSL:=TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
   Params:=TStringList.Create;
   try
      Params.Delimiter:='&';
      Params.StrictDelimiter:=True;

      // HTTP Client Options
      HTTP.HTTPOptions:=HTTP.HTTPOptions+[hoKeepOrigProtocol]-[hoForceEncodeParams];
      HTTP.ConnectTimeout:=5000;
      HTTP.ReadTimeout:=20000;
      HTTP.ProtocolVersion:=pv1_1;
      HTTP.IOHandler:=SSL;
      HTTP.HandleRedirects:=True;
      HTTP.Request.Accept:='text/plain, */*';
      HTTP.Request.AcceptLanguage:='en-US';
      HTTP.Request.ContentType:='application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
      HTTP.Request.CharSet:='utf-8';
      HTTP.Request.UserAgent:='MyApp/1.0 (Language=Delphi)';
      HTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('x-amazon-user-agent',HTTP.Request.UserAgent);

      // generate the timestamp per Amazon specs
      Timestamp:=TIso8601.UtcDateTimeToIso8601(TIso8601.ToUtc(Now));
      // we can change the timestamp to match a value from the Scratchpad as a way to validate the signature:
      //Timestamp:='2014-05-09T20:32:28Z';

      // add required parameters from API function GetOrder
      Params.Add('Action=GetOrder');
      Params.Add('SellerId='+MerchantID);
      Params.Add('AWSAccessKeyId='+AwsAccessKey);
      Params.Add('Timestamp='+Timestamp);
      Params.Add('Version='+ApiVersion);
      Params.Add('SignatureVersion=2');
      Params.Add('SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256');
      Params.Add('AmazonOrderId.Id.1='+OrderID);
      // generate the signature using the parameters above
      Params.Add('Signature='+GetSignature(Params.Text,CallUri));

      // after generating the signature, make sure all values are properly URL-Encoded
      for i:=0 to Params.Count-1 do begin
         Key:=Params.Names[i];
         Value:=ParamEnc(Params.ValueFromIndex[i]);
         QueryString:=QueryString+Key+'='+Value+'&';
      end;
      Delete(QueryString,Length(QueryString),1);

      // there are two ways to make the call...
      // #1: according to the documentation, all parameters are supposed to be in
      // the URL, and the body stream is supposed to be empty
      SS:=TStringStream.Create;
      try
         try
            Log('POST '+CallUri+'?'+QueryString);
            S:=HTTP.Post('https://mws.amazonservices.com'+CallUri+'?'+QueryString,SS);
         except
            on E1:EIdHTTPProtocolException do begin
               Log('RawHeaders='+#$D#$A+HTTP.Request.RawHeaders.Text);
               Log('Protocol Exception:'+#$D#$A+StringReplace(E1.ErrorMessage,#10,#$D#$A,[rfReplaceAll]));
            end;
            on E2:Exception do
               Log('Unknown Exception: '+E2.Message);
         end;
         Log('ResponseText='+S);
      finally
         SS.Free;
      end;

      // #2: both the Scratchpad and the CSharp client sample provided by Amazon
      // do things in a different way, though... they POST the parameters in the
      // body of the call, not in the query string
      SS:=TStringStream.Create(QueryString,TEncoding.UTF8);
      try
         try
            SS.Seek(0,0);
            Log('POST '+CallUri+' (parameters in body/stream)');
            S:=HTTP.Post('https://mws.amazonservices.com'+CallUri,SS);
         except
            on E1:EIdHTTPProtocolException do begin
               Log('RawHeaders='+#$D#$A+HTTP.Request.RawHeaders.Text);
               Log('Protocol Exception:'+#$D#$A+StringReplace(E1.ErrorMessage,#10,#$D#$A,[rfReplaceAll]));
            end;
            on E2:Exception do
               Log('Unknown Exception: '+E2.Message);
         end;
         Log('ResponseText='+S);
      finally
         SS.Free;
      end;
   finally
      Params.Free;
      SSL.Free;
      HTTP.Free;
   end;
end;
```

If I assemble a GetOrder call in Scratchpad, then paste the timestamp of that call into the code above, I get EXACTLY the same query string here, with the same signature and size, etc. But my Indy request must be encoding things differently, because the MWS server doesn't like the call.

I know MWS is at least "reading" the query string, because if I change the timestamp to an old date, it returns a "request expired" error instead.

Amazon's tech support is clueless, posting a message every day with basic stuff like "Make sure the secret key is correct" (as if getting a signature with HMAC-SHA256 and MD5 would work without a valid key!!!!).

One more thing: if I use Wireshark to "watch" the raw request from both the code above and the C-Sharp Amazon sample code, I can't tell a difference either.  However, I'm not sure Wireshark makes a distinction between UTF-8 and ASCII or whatever encoding the text being shown has.  I still think it has to do with bad UTC-8 encoding or something like that.

Ideas and suggestions on how to properly encode the API call to please the Amazon gods are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using something like fiddler to interrogate calls from other tools to the service? You could then compare your generated requests with their ones.

Comment: @Graymatter: I used Wireshark to watch the traffic, and I also redirected calls from my app and from the Amazon library samples to my own web server (so I could compare the requests). In both cases, the requests and the signatures match perfectly. That's why I think it may be an encoding problem.

Comment: The reason I suggested fiddler is that they have a number of different views including hex which would let you see the raw data being passed around.

Comment: Interesting. I'll take a look at that option too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem: Indy (and Synapse too) adds the port number to the "Host" header line, and I had not realized that extra bit until I watched the headers more closely with Fiddler (thanks, @Graymatter!!!!).

When I change the endpoint to be mws.amazonservices.com:443 (instead of just mws.amazonservices), then my signature is calculated the same way as the AWS server's, and everything works perfectly.

Comment: `TIdHTTP` adds the port to the `Host` header only if you request an HTTP url on a port other than 80, or an HTTPS url on a port other than 443. Otherwise it omits the port since the default port is being used.

Comment: @Remy: not sure this is accurate. I'm using Indy 10.5.5 and the example above does not even specify a port, but :443 was added. It also happens to the Synapse library (I used that to troubleshoot when I wasn't sure of what was going on). However, no port number was added with .NET or JavaScript calls (both with IE and Chrome).

Comment: In fact, I just created a barebones test case by dropping a TIdHTTP and a TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL to a form and then issued a GET request to the Amazon server.  Here's the captured raw data of the request:

GET https://mws.amazonservices.com:443/ HTTP/1.1
Host: mws.amazonservices.com:443
Accept: text/html, */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)

Could it be a setting somewhere that is making my Indy behave differently than what's intended?

Comment: The fact that the Host:Port is appearing in the `GET` line itself means you must be going through a proxy, otherwise `TIdHTTP` would not put the Host:Port on that line at all. That makes a difference. BTW, you are not using the latest version of Indy, which is 10.6.0.5137. There have been changes to `TIdHTTP`'s internals since 10.5.5, which is several years old now.

Comment: I thought about the proxy too, but the fact is: signing the request WITH 443 makes it match Amazon's own calculation. Without the port number, the signatures won't match, so the remote host must be getting the Host header like that too. And yes, I know that I should be using the newest version, so maybe this is a great chance to do it. :-)