# Delphi HMAC SHA512 signed calls to Bittrex Exchange

Tags: delphi, indy, hmac, sha512

I have been working on this for a while and I just can't get a successful response from the server.
All documentation for this can be found at the [Bittrex Exchange Wesite](https://www.bittrex.com/Home/Api)

The main crux of the signature bit can be found under the heading **Authentication**

---

The hashing file I have been using can be found at [Fundamentals](http://fundementals.sourceforge.net/dl.html) on SourceForge. It is the one at the bottom called Fundamentals Hash 4.00.15

The reason I have been using this file is a very simple one, it seems to be the only one giving me a correct answer. Or should I say, it is giving me the correct answer compared to the result this [Hashing Website](http://hash.online-convert.com/sha512-generator) is giving me.

I've tried using the Indy components to generate the correct hash, but it never seems to match the value from the website. Maybe I'm not using it correctly or the right libraries or something, but I will add the example for that as well that I created.
(As I write this, I've just tested again, and it does seem like I am getting the right answer, go figure, maybe I am using a better OpenSSL library. Anyway, I will also put my INDY example down below as well).

---

```
function Test: String;
const
  FAPIKey = 'APIKEY';
  FAPISecret = 'APISECRET';
  FURL = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalances?apikey=%s&nonce=%d';
var
  FPost, FSignature: String;
  FNonce: Integer;
  Response: TStringStream;
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  SSL:TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  Result := '';

  FNonce := DateTimeToUnix(Now);
  FPost := Format(FURL, [FAPIKey, FNonce]);

  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(HTTP);
    try
      HTTP.IOHandler := SSL;

      FSignature := SHA512DigestToHex(CalcHMAC_SHA512(FAPISecret, FPost));
      HTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('apisign', FSignature);

      Response := TStringStream.Create;
      try
        HTTP.Get(FPost, Response);
        Result := Response.DataString;
      finally
        Response := nil;
      end;
    finally
      SSL := nil;
    end;
  finally
    HTTP := nil;
  end;
end;
```

---

Prior to using this version for the hashing I was only ever getting 
'{"success":false,"message":"APISIGN_NOT_PROVIDED","result":null}'
I finally moved on when I worked out the custom HTTP headers and am now getting
'{"success":false,"message":"INVALID_SIGNATURE","result":null}'
Could it be something simple as an invalid nonce, or one that is too old?
Does everything look ok or am I missing some basic component settings for the INDY components?

---

```
function Test: String;
const
  FAPIKey = 'APIKEY';
  FAPISecret = 'APISECRET';
  FURL = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalances?apikey=%s&nonce=%d';
var
  FPost, FSignature: String;
  FNonce: Integer;
  Response: TStringStream;
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  SSL:TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  FSHA512Hasher: TIdHMACSHA512;
begin
  Result := '';
  if not LoadOpenSSLLibrary then exit;

  FNonce := DateTimeToUnix(Now);
  FPost := Format(FURL, [FAPIKey, FNonce]);

  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(HTTP);
    try
      HTTP.IOHandler := SSL;

      FSHA512Hasher := TIdHMACSHA512.Create;
      try
        FSHA512Hasher.Key := ToBytes(FAPISecret);
        FSignature := Lowercase(ToHex(FSHA512Hasher.HashValue(ToBytes(FPost))));
      finally
        FSHA512Hasher := nil;
      end;

      HTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('apisign', FSignature);

      Response := TStringStream.Create;
      try
        HTTP.Get(FPost, Response);
        Result := Response.DataString;
      finally
        Response := nil;
      end;
    finally
      SSL := nil;
    end;
  finally
    HTTP := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Are you taking Unicode into account? Ansi strings hash differently than Unicode strings for character values > #127.

Comment: Just a sidenote, there are a lot if `:= nil;` where I would expect a `Free`.

Comment: I agree bummi, I am being lazy and not really focused on memory leaks atm

Comment: Thanks Remy, think I should be doing something like TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes instead?

Comment: No joy with that smal change

Comment: I did actually look at another question you commented on Remy [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573799/amazon-mws-api-call-using-delphi-indy) but the bit that was doing the hashing in this one was obviously in another function called GetSignature which wasn't posted.

Comment: Ok looks like it might be a component setting maybe.
I got a friend of mine to create the PHP version of the code shown on the original website into a webpage where I can enter the various parameters.
On generation of the hash from what I supplied, I am creating the same signature, so for some reason the HTTP.Get(FPost, Response) isn't working correctly?

Comment: Don't forget that there's an expiration on a signature, so simply generating one with the PHP script, copying that into your code and sending it as a request with the HTTP Client isn't going to necessarily be valid.

Comment: Also, you aren't URL-Encoding your strings! You need to URL-Encode the string BEFORE you hash it!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which I eventually figured out.  I used the hmac.pas unit which I found via google search, but had to modify it to work with 10.1 Seattle (specifically IDBytes is a little different).

IMPORTANT: I also had to modify the hmac.pas unit to remove the '0x' from the front of the HexStr variation of the functions.

ALSO: I made all inputs ansistring.

My test function for this is as follows.

```
function TBTXClient.Get(sCommand, sAddParams: string): string;
var
  sURL: string;
  nonce: string;
  res: string;
  sec2: string;
  sha: TIDHashSha256;
  hmac: TIdHMAC;
  hash: string;
  ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  nonce := inttostr(getticker);
  sURL := 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/'+sCommand+'?apikey='+MY_KEY+'&nonce='+nonce+sAddParams;

  hash := THMACUtils<TIDHMacSha512>.HMAC_HexStr(MY_SECRET,sURL);

  //Debug.Log('url = '+sUrl);
  //Debug.Log('hash = '+hash);
  QuickHTTPSGet(sURL, res, 'apisign', hash);

  result := res;

end;
```

My Modified version of the hmac.pas unit (has some new dependencies)

```
unit hmac;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  EncdDecd,
  IdHMAC,
  IdSSLOpenSSL,
  helpers.indy,
  idglobal,
  IdHash;

type
  localstringtype = ansistring;

  THMACUtils<T: TIdHMAC, constructor> = class
  public
    class function HMAC(aKey, aMessage: localstringtype): TIdBytes;
    class function HMAC_HexStr(aKey, aMessage: localstringtype): localstringtype;
    class function HMAC_Base64(aKey, aMessage: localstringtype): localstringtype;
  end;

implementation

class function THMACUtils<T>.HMAC(aKey, aMessage: localstringtype): TIdBytes;
var
  _HMAC: T;
begin
  if not IdSSLOpenSSL.LoadOpenSSLLibrary then Exit;
  _HMAC:= T.Create;
  try
    _HMAC.Key := AnsiStringToIDBytes(aKey);
    Result:= _HMAC.HashValue(AnsiStringToIDBytes(aMessage));
  finally
    _HMAC.Free;
  end;
end;

class function THMACUtils<T>.HMAC_HexStr(aKey, aMessage: localstringtype):     localstringtype;
var
  I: Byte;
begin
  Result:= '';//'0x';
  for I in HMAC(aKey, aMessage) do
    Result:= Result + IntToHex(I, 2);
end;

class function THMACUtils<T>.HMAC_Base64(aKey, aMessage: localstringtype):     localstringtype;
var
  _HMAC: TIdBytes;
begin
  _HMAC:= HMAC(aKey, aMessage);
  Result:= EncodeBase64(_HMAC, Length(_HMAC));
end;

end.
```

You'll probably also want this helper unit.

```
unit helpers.indy;

interface

uses
  idglobal, types, classes, sysutils, typex;


function TBytesToIDBytes(b: TBytes): TIDBytes;
function AnsiStringToIDBytes(a: ansistring): TIDBytes;

implementation


function TBytesToIDBytes(b: TBytes): TIDBytes;
var
  t: ni;
begin
  setlength(result, length(b));
  for t := low(b) to high(b) do
    result[t] := b[t];

end;
function AnsiStringToIDBytes(a: ansistring): TIDBytes;
var
  t: ni;
begin
  setlength(result, length(a));
  for t := 0  to length(a)-1 do
    result[t] := ord(a[STRZ+t]);

end;
```

And this cheesy function, which I borrowed from my own https unit shows how to handle the header params.

```
function QuickHTTPSGet(sURL: ansistring; out sOutREsponse: string; 
  addHead: string =''; addHeadValue: string = ''): boolean;
var
  htp: IXMLhttprequest;
begin

  htp := ComsXMLHTTP30.create();
  try
    htp.open('GET', sURL, false, null, null);
    if addHead <> '' then
      htp.setRequestHeader(addHead, addHeadValue);
    htp.send('');
    result := htp.status = 200;
    if result then
      sOutREsponse := htp.responsetext
    else
      soutResponse := 'error '+inttostr(htp.status);
  except
    on e: Exception do begin
      result := false;
      sOutResponse := 'error '+e.message;
    end;
  end;

end;
```